# not able to cat trough system call

Tags: c

I am trying to `cat` some file into another new files, but to my surprise its not working.
Able to do the same if i execute the same command on terminal, but through `system` call, it not working.
I just need a new set of eyes to look and point out the problem please

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dirent.h> 
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

#define COMMON_COMMAND "cd %s;cat %s >> %s"
#define RPATH "/home/spark/R/"
   
#define R_CERTIFICATE_NOT_FOUND 2 
#define RESULT_NOT_FOUND_FILE 5
#define DIR_CERTIFICATE_NOT_FOUND 6
#define RESULT_SUCCESS 0
#define BUFFER_SIZE 1000

/*Final file*/
#define COMMON_FILE "common_file_"

static int prepare_FinFiles(const char *rpath,char *common_file);
static int ReadFiles(const char *path,char *common_file);

int main()
{
    char Finfile[BUFFER_SIZE] = {0};
    char cmd[50] = {0};
    struct timeval t1;
    gettimeofday(&t1, NULL);
    srand(t1.tv_usec);
    prepare_FinFiles(RPATH,Finfile);
    strcpy(cmd,"cat ");
    strcat(cmd,Finfile);
    printf(" cmd output ==> \n");
    system(cmd); 
    return 0;
}

static int prepare_FinFiles(const char *rpath,char *common_file)
{
    char command[BUFFER_SIZE] = {0};
    char temp_files[BUFFER_SIZE] = {0};
    int32_t count_no_files = 0;
    char cmd[BUFFER_SIZE] = {0};
    sprintf(common_file, "%s%d%s", "/home/spark/"COMMON_FILE,random(),".txt");
    strcpy(cmd,"touch ");
    strcat(cmd, common_file);
    system(cmd);
    if( ReadFiles(rpath,common_file) == RESULT_NOT_FOUND_FILE)
    {
        return R_CERTIFICATE_NOT_FOUND;
    }
    else if(retVal == DIR_CERTIFICATE_NOT_FOUND)
    {
        printf("dir not found\n");
        return DIR_CERTIFICATE_NOT_FOUND;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("R read success\n");
        char Finfile[BUFFER_SIZE] = {0};
        char cmd[50] = {0};
        strcpy(cmd,"cat ");
        strcat(cmd,common_file);
        printf("cmd : %s\n",cmd);
        printf("The return value is: %d\n", WEXITSTATUS(system(cmd))); 
    }
}

static int32_t ReadFiles(const char *path,char *common_file)
{
    DIR *dir = opendir(path);
    struct dirent *dp;
    char command[BUFFER_SIZE] = {0};
    char temp_files[BUFFER_SIZE] = {0};
    int count_no_files =0;  
    
    printf("Reading from %s path\n", path);
    
    if(!dir)
    {
        return DIR_CERTIFICATE_NOT_FOUND;
    }
    else
    {
        while ((dp = readdir(dir)) != NULL)
        {
            if( strncmp(dp->d_name,".",strlen(".")) &&
                strncmp(dp->d_name,"..",strlen(".."))
            )
            {
                strncat(temp_files,dp->d_name,strlen(dp->d_name));
                strncat(temp_files," ",strlen(" "));
                count_no_files++;
            }
        }
        if(count_no_files == 0)
        {
            return RESULT_NOT_FOUND_FILE;
        }
        else
        {
            memset(command,0,sizeof(command));
            sprintf(command, COMMON_COMMAND, path,temp_files,common_file);  
            printf("command = %s\n", command);
            return RESULT_SUCCESS;
        }
    }
}
```

**output**

Reading from /home/spark/R/ path

command = cd /home/spark/R/;cat file1.txt >> /home/spark/R/common_file_931058571.txt

R read success

cmd : cat /home/spark/R/common_file_931058571.txt

The return value is: 0

Comment: `Finfile` can contain a string up to `BUFFER_SIZE - 1` characters in length. How will this fit in `cmd`?

Comment: By the way, the code you show isn't a proper [mcve]. It won't even build without errors.

Comment: Is that whole code required to reproduce the problem? Does it work properly if you call `system` with string literals? If it is also failing with string literals, you might remove 95% of that code and create the required **minimal** reproducible example.

Comment: Not necessarily related to your problem, but your usage of `strncat` is useless. If you always provide length of appended string, you will get same result as with `strcat`.

Comment: @Gerhardh, it works with minimal code where i add only cat code

Comment: Minimal reproducible example ... **that still has the problem**. It's great you have one that doesn't have the problem already. You'll be able to compare them, and hopefully it's then clearer what's happening.

Comment: The command you print, is created using `COMMON_COMMAND` which is only used in `ReadFiles` where you do not even call `system`. You return from that function immediately after printing the command string.

Comment: If the same command works fine if you just provide the string to `system` then it is very likely not related to the `system` call at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but through system call, it not working

Because you do not call `system` at all.

Your code contains 3 calls to `system`:

```
// in main
    system(cmd); // cmd contains "cat /home/spark/common_file_<random>.txt"
```

```
// in prepare_FinFile
    system(cmd); // cmd contains "touch /home/spark/common_file_<random>.txt"
...
       printf("cmd : %s\n",cmd);
       printf("The return value is: %d\n", WEXITSTATUS(system(cmd))); 
       // cmd contains "cat /home/spark/R/common_file_931058571.txt"
```

The command in question would be this:

```
            printf("command = %s\n", command);
// command contains "cd /home/spark/R/;cat file1.txt >> /home/spark/R/common_file_931058571.txt"
            return RESULT_SUCCESS;
```

But you never execute it. You just print it.

Comment: you got it , that why i said a new set of eyes, thanks a lot Gerhardh

Comment: That is exactly why you are expected to create a minimum example that still reproduces the problem. With only relevant code it is much more obvious.